# batch file passing variable to a text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, text, echo, text-files

```
ECHO off

FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "%pth%"==%%~da%%~pa (
        ECHO "%pth%">>Liste.txt
    )
    SET pth=%%~da%%~pa
 )
```

I want to pass a path just one time; not for every file subdirectories includes. How `%pth%` string variable can be passed to a text file? Why does this code not work?

Is this code wrong?

```
FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    SET pth=%%~da%%~pa
    ECHO %pth%>>Liste.txt
 )
```

The code below works. It passes the paths for each file. If there is files more than one in a subdirectory it passes same path as many as the number o files. I don't want it. I want passing the same path once.

```
 FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO ECHO %%~da%%~pa>>Liste.txt
```

Comment: Which time do you want to pass the path? The first time? The last time? Right now it's inside the for loop with no other conditionals, so it gets passed every time.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote wrog code. I have corrected now. The first block which I want to work.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Which one of the many paths do you want to add to the text file?

Comment: Problem is, IF condition does not work and %pth% string parameter can not be passed to text file.

Comment: This code works in a directory whic has subdirectories includig subdirectories. The last subdirectories include files. FOR loop works for each file and the code which I whave written in the last one line block works and it passes the same path for each file for as many file as the subdirectory includes. I want to pass the path just one time for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told use very clearly (with an example) what you want to do.

Fundamentally, within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Hence

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "!pth!"=="%%~dpa" (
        ECHO "!pth!">>Liste.txt
    )
    SET "pth=%%~dpa"
 )
```

should work (I haven't tried it)

OR

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do >>liste.txt echo %%a
```

which is probably easier (produce a listing of all subdirectories)

Note that `%%~da%%~pa` is equivalent to `%%~dpa`

Edited to include required <kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: @ECHO off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
     IF NOT "!pth!"==%%~dpa (
      ECHO %%~dpa>>Liste.txt 
      )
     SET "pth=%%~dpa"
    )

Comment: Thanks. I write the code as an answer for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
dir /ad /s /b >> liste.txt
```

This should do the same your code trying to do: append all the subfolders into the target file.

The problem with the original code is how the parser handles variables. In batch files, when a line or a block of lines is reached, the parser removes all variable reads, replacing them with its value **before** executing the code. So, if inside a line/block a variable is changed, this changed value can not be retrieved inside the same line/block as the read operation was removed. The usual way to handle it is to enable delayed expansion. This allows to change where needed variable read syntax from `%var%` into `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the code is executed.

So, in your case, filtering the path of the files

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "pth="
FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "!pth!"=="%%~dpa" (
        ECHO "%%~dpa">>Liste.txt
        SET "pth=%%~dpa"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works in a manner which I want. But with this code string manuplation is not possible which I want to use in the future. I especially ask if there is a way to pass as string variable to a text file. What is wrong with my code? If there is a way to pass variable I may have opportunity to manuplate string.

Comment: @kitapmitap, well, answer updated, but while i was editing it Magoo included a equivalent answer. Nothing new here.

Answer (score 0):

@Magoo: Thanks. You show me the right.
The code below is which I want; but "if conditional" does not work: ("!pth!"==%%~dpa) check is always return FALSE I think.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "!pth!"==%%~dpa (
        ECHO %%~dpa>>Liste.txt 
        )
    SET "pth=%%~dpa"
)
```

@Magoo: The question is how the code above works like your one line code below:

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do >>liste.txt echo %%a
```

or like written by @MC ND:

```
dir /ad /s /b >> liste.txt
```

Comment: Yes, your `if` statement will always return false in its current form because if left side has quotes and the right side does not. Additionally, `~dp` is _exclusively_ for `for /F` loops.

Comment: I quoted right side and it works. @SomethingDark thanks.

Comment: @SomethingDark : "~dp is exclusively for for /F loops" - not so, sorry.

Comment: @Magoo well this is what happens when I use for /F loops exclusively... >_>

Answer (score 0):

At last this works. Thanks everyone.
code:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /r %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "!pth!"=="%%~dpa" (
        ECHO %%~dpa>>Liste.txt 
    )
SET "pth=%%~dpa"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the `IF %pth%` condition outside the `FOR` and it should work.

What exactly do you want to do ? Perhaps theres a simpler way.

Comment: This last code I have wriitten just now passes path for every file. It writes same path as many as number of files the directory includes. I want to check if the path is same and not pass that string.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote wrog code. I have corrected now. Which I want to work is the first block.

Comment: This code works in a directory which has subdirectories includig subdirectories. The last subdirectories include files. FOR loop works for each file and the code which I have written in the last one line block works and it passes the same path for each file for as many file as the subdirectory includes. I want to pass the path just one time for a subdirectory.